# How many flips would it take to obtain the sequence HTHT when flipping a coin

Tags: probability, expectation

I keep on getting 25 when I compute

$$E(X) = 4(\frac{1}{2})^4 + \frac{1}{2}(1+E(X)) + (\frac{1}{2}^2)(1+E(X)) + (\frac{1}{2}^3)(3+E(X)) +  (\frac{1}{2}^4)(3+E(X))  $$

Comment: The answer is 20. What about explaining the identity in your post?

Comment: How do you arrive at 20 am I using the wrong equation to compute the expectation @Did

Comment: Which part of "Please explain how you arrived at this identity" do you fail to understand? Or did you copy it from somewhere?

Comment: @Did I adapted the formula used here for computing consecutive heads but I changed the number of wasted flips depending on if the sequence could be restarted https://www.codechef.com/wiki/tutorial-expectation

Comment: Then why $1+E(X)$ as the factor of $1/2^2$ then?

Comment: @Did For the sequence of HH only 1 flip was wasted but the sequence occurs with probability (1/2)^2

Comment: There is no reason to expect that the mean time needed to see HTHT appear starting from H is equal to the mean time needed to see HTHT appear starting from nothing, minus 1. (And actually, the former is equal to the latter minus 2.)

Answer (score 0):

Let states be enumerated for $\phi$, H, HT, HTH, and HTHT, solving for expected number of flips from the given state. Write the state transition equations as

$$
\tau_0 = \frac12\tau_0 + \frac12\tau_1 + 1 \\
\tau_1 = \frac12\tau_1 + \frac12\tau_2 + 1 \\
\tau_2 = \frac12\tau_0 + \frac12\tau_3 + 1 \\
\tau_3 = \frac12\tau_1 + \frac12\tau_4 + 1 \\
$$

Since $\tau_4 = 0$, this can be simplified to

$ X = 
\begin{pmatrix}
     1  &  -1 &    0 &    0 \\
     0  &   1  &  -1 &    0 \\
    -1   &  0   &  2  &  -1 \\
     0   & -1    & 0   &  2 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$

solve $X^{-1}[2 \; 2 \; 2 \;2]^T$ for each given state.
$$X^{-1}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
3 & 4 & 2 & 1  \\
2 & 4 & 2 & 1  \\
2 & 3 & 2 & 1  \\
1 & 2 & 1 & 1  \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

and the expected number of flips are [20, 18, 16, 10].  That is from initial state it will take 20 flips.  Starting from H will be 18.